# soldering temperature/tip guides?

Tags: soldering

I've got a Weller soldering station with settable temperature and interchangeable tips.

Is there a table or general guidelines for temperatures and tips for different soldering tasks, such as:

- wire-wire, thick
- wire-wire, 20 gauge
- wire to PC board
- through-hole chip on PC board

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some soldering experts may disagree with me but I usually always use 750-800°F (400-425°C).  It seems the biggest variable is the tip.  For through hole and wire to wire I use a very big tip.  I use a smaller tip for SMT.  It has always seemed to me, for correct heat transfer, tip size is much more important than temperature.  If you find yourself needing to hold the iron against your parts too long (more than a few seconds) I'd use a bigger tip.  Wire to wire usually isn't as critical or easy to damage as ICs, usually just don't want to start melting the insulation.  Following this method I've never burnt a chip to death.  Killed them plenty of other ways though, and I'm definitely not a professional solderer.

Answer (score 5):

You should select the correct tip for a particular joint, keeping the temperature constant. The tip should be about the same size as the object being soldered. The temperature depends on the type of solder.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the temperature matters much, just that you get the material you are soldering to hot. Once the material is hot, allow the solder to flow from the heated material to your soldering iron. If you are getting big beads of solder on your soldering iron, you are doing things backwards. Make sure to move your soldering Iron away from the solder as it flows.

If your not able to maintain a hot temperature on the object being soldered to, then you may want to try either a larger tip, and or a higher temperature.